# How to upgrade the MAT-file in matlab into version 7.3 and more

Tags: matlab

I have Matlab version 2019a, when I try to save a file whose size more than 1Gb, it gives me this message :

```
"Save operation failed. This variable cannot be saved to MAT-file whose version is older than 7.3, because it is too large. would you like to save in MAT-file whose version 7.3? "
```

That means that my MAT-file version is older than 7.3, is that right ?  So how can I update it ?

thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error relates to the default version choice (v7) Matlab uses when `save` is called without the `version` argument which does not support variables larger than 2^31 bytes.

Have a read of this [documentation](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/save.html#btox10b-1-version).

Within that documentation page there is an example of how you should call the `save` function if would like to store large variables:

```
save('example.mat','A','B','-v7.3')
```

Comment: thank you so much, but I need the file to be saved in version which is newer. because the file saved in version 7.3 can't be read y python directly.